# Tabulator.js table elements retrieve the index of the row and serve as a control element to other plots

Tags: javascript, callback, tabulator

I am using tabulator package 4.3.0 to work on a webpage. The table generated by the package is going to be the control element of a few other plots. In order to achieve this, I have been adding a dataFiltered function when defining the table variable. But instead of getting the order of the rows in my data object, I want to figure a way to get the index of the rows in the filtered table.

Currently, I searched the manual a little bit and have written the code analogue to this:

```
dataFiltered: function(filters,rows){
console.log(rows[0]._row.data)
console.log(rows[0].getPosition(true));
}
```

But the getPosition always returned -1, which refers to that the row is not found in the filtered table. I also generated a demo to show the real situ when running the function. with this link: https://jsfiddle.net/Binny92/3kbn8zet/53/.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me explain a little bit of how could I get the real index of the row in the filtered data so that I could update the plot accordingly and why I am always getting -1 when running the code written in this way.

In addition, I wonder whether there is a way to retrieve the data also when the user is sorting the table. It's a pity that code using the following strategy is not working in the way I am expecting since it is not reacting to the sort action and will not show the information when loading the page for the first time.

```
$('#trialTable').on('change',function(x){console.log("Yes")})
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the ***dataFiltered*** callback is triggered after the rows are filtered but before they have been laid out on the table, so they wont necessarily be ready by the time you call the ***getPosition*** function on them.

You might do better to use the ***renderComplete*** callback, which will also handle the scenario when the table is sorted, which would change the row positions.

You could then use the ***getRows*** function passing in the value `"active"` as the first augment return only rows that have passed the filter:

```js
renderComplete: function(){
    var rows = table.getRows("active");
    console.log(rows[0].getPosition(true));
}
```

On a side note i notice you are trying to access the `_row` property to access the row data. By convention underscore properties are considered private in JavaScript and should not be accessed as it can result in unstable system behaviour.

Tabulator has an extensive set of functions on the [Row Component](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/components#component-row) to allow you to access anything you need. In the case of accessing a rows data, there is the ***getData*** function

```js
var data = row.getData();
```

Comment: Thank you, Oli for your advice on the renderComplete function (couldn't believe I missed that in the manual) and the nice interactive tabulator package. Also, the side note really helps a for stopping me from potentially ruining the system.